# Performing mathematical operations on numbers within a string

Tags: ruby

Given a string containing comma-separated numbers, is it possible to perform mathematical operations on them?

For example, how can I take the string `"123,456,789"`, extract the numbers from within it, and perform operations like `123 + 456` or `456 - 123`?

Comment: So what? What is the question?

Comment: How about using `split` on your string? Like `s.split(",")` and it will give you an array of the numbers on the string. Then you can perform whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only messing around, you can use `eval` and `gsub`

```
>> eval '123,456,789'.gsub(',', '*') # 44253432
>> eval '123,456,789'.gsub(',', '+') # 1368
>> eval '123,456,789'.gsub(',', '-') # -1122
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inject`, `split`, and `map` methods
eg :

```
"123,32,3,4,5,6, 2,34".split(",").map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)
```

You can use eval also, but `eval` is slow and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

You can split string in array, by use `split(',')`
Now, you may use `to_i` with any array element.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
s = "123,456,789"

s.split(',').reduce(0) do |result, number|
  result = result + number.to_i
end
```

Change the sign inside `reduce` block from `+` to `-` or whatever you need.

Comment: If you do that with `*`, that will always give `0`. I don't know if that is what you intended.

Comment: sawa, you're right. No idea what i was thinking. Will update the answer

Comment: Along your lines, perhaps you can do: `s.split(",").map(&:to_i).inject(:+)`.